# Segregate a column values in 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have got data like this:

```
Col
Texas[x]
Dallas
Austin
California[x]
Los Angeles
San Francisco
```

What i want is this:

```
col1              Col2
Texas[x]          Dallas
                  Austin
California[x]     Los Angeles
                  San Francisco
```

Please help!

Comment: Please format your dataframes correctly. I have no idea what it looks like.

Comment: Does your data actually contain [x] to represent the states from the cities? Based on your dataframe you want a multiindex with the index being state in col1 and col2 being the city associated with that state.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh yes, it does have that identifier for state.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, it is my first posting in here and i immediately realized as soon as i posted it. It is good now.

Comment: So do you want a multiindex based on the state? Please post the entire script so I can see how you are creating this dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str.extract to create columns and then clean up

```
df.Col.str.extract('(.*\[x\])?(.*)').ffill()\
.replace('', np.nan).dropna()\
.rename(columns = {0:'Col1', 1: 'Col2'})\
.set_index('Col1')

                 Col2
Col1    
Texas [x]       Dallas
Texas [x]       Austin
California [x]  Los Angeles
California [x]  San Francisco
```

Update: To address the follow-up question.

```
df.Col.str.extract('(.*\[x\])?(.*)').ffill()\
.replace('', np.nan).dropna()\
.rename(columns = {0:'Col1', 1: 'Col2'})
```

You get

```
    Col1            Col2
1   Texas[x]        Dallas
2   Texas[x]        Austin
4   California[x]   Los Angeles
5   California[x]   San Francisco
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Only minor tweak i had to do was df[0].str instead of df.Col.str as it was not recognized by Python notebook.

Comment: You are weocome.Col is the column name in your sample dataframe. May be in you actual data, its 0,1 so on..

Comment: Just remove the last line, set_index()

Comment: Just extending the solution a little further to address another issue wherein if we just keep Col1 and Col2 as columns not resetting col1 as index... is it possible to display the data frame like this: DataFrame( [ ['Texas[x]', 'Dallas'], ['Texas[x]', 'Austin'], ['California[x]', 'Los Angeles'], ['California[x]', 'San Francisco'] ], Columns = ['col1', 'col 2'] )

Comment: I had mistakenly posted my comments before completing. I deleted that comment and posted a new one wherein i'm asking to display the out put in a specific format detailed in that comment. Apologies for inconvenience!

Comment: What is the difference between the output and what I posted in the answer?

Comment: My output requirement is one dimensional DataFrame wherein each row is a list containing col1 & col2 values and at the end of all these lists there should be  a mention of columns like columns = ['col1', 'col2']. Just to draw a parallel of the kind of output i'm looking for - the output we get if we run df.values.

Comment: Try df.Col.str.extract('(.*\[x\])?(.*)').ffill()\
.replace('', np.nan).dropna()\
.rename(columns = {0:'Col1', 1: 'Col2'}).T.reset_index().T.apply(list, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `[x]` represents state in a list. You can try to iterate over the dataframe using `iterrows`. Something like this:

```
state = None  # initialize as None, in case something goes wrong  
city = None
rowlist = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # get the state
    if '[x]' in row['Col']:
        state = row['Col']
        continue
    # now, get the cities
    city = row['Col']
    rowlist.append([state, city])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rowlist)
```

This assumes that your initial dataframe is called `df` and column name is `Col`, and only works if cities are followed by states, which it seems like they do from your data sample.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet as the answer above was more succinct so i went with that. I will definitely try when i get some time. Thanks for reply though!

Comment: Yes, Vaishali's answer is very nice. It's faster and more pythonic than mine. Mine is simpler and more readable though, I think :)